# How should I form a list property type with my own type

Tags: kotlin, kotlinpoet

I am trying to form below final kotlin code

```
val participants: List<AbstractParty>
```

I tried to use below code in kotlinpoet but it shows error, I think it is not correct, but don't know how should I fix it. Any one can help? Thanks.

```
PropertySpec.builder("participants", List<ClassName("AbstractParty">)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on whether you have a reference to a class or if you need to create its name from Strings, you can do either this:

```
PropertySpec.builder("participants",
     ParameterizedTypeName.get(List::class, AbstractParty::class)
).build()
```

Or this:

```
PropertySpec.builder("participants",
    ParameterizedTypeName.get(
            List::class.asClassName(),
            ClassName("some.pckg.name", "AbstractParty"))
).build()
```

A hint to finding out these sorts of things: KotlinPoet has pretty extensive tests, you can find examples of almost anything in there.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, I have the reference for that class so the second one meet my need. Thanks a lot, I may have lots of questions during my trying of Kotlinpoet, am not sure do we have some sample codes about generate different type of codes, that would be very helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure if you've seen my edit already, but you should look at the tests [here](https://github.com/square/kotlinpoet/tree/master/src/test/java/com/squareup/kotlinpoet) for examples. It's also handy to clone the project locally and then you can search it much better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parameterizedBy()` extension:

```
PropertySpec.builder(
    "participants",
    List::class.asClassName().parameterizedBy(ClassName("some.pckg.name", "AbstractParty")
).build()
```

https://square.github.io/kotlinpoet/1.x/kotlinpoet/kotlinpoet/com.squareup.kotlinpoet/-parameterized-type-name/-companion/parameterized-by.html